# How to build Artifactory Dockerfile with custom repositories?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, artifactory

I am looking for a solution how to extend official Artifactory Docker Image (`docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss`).

I want to add custom local repositories and new user with defined credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuration+Files#ConfigurationFiles-BootstrappingtheGlobalConfiguration for repository configuration and https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuration+Files#ConfigurationFiles-BootstrappingtheSecurityConfiguration for security configuration.